# Java GraphQL Resolver for iterable object: Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, graphql, graphql-java

I'm implementing a GraphQL server using Spring Boot, however, I'm running into some trouble when writing resolvers for models that have many-to-many relationships. The function `getBooks` in the below resolver class throws the following error:

```java
package com.example.DemoGraphQL.resolver;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLResolver;
import com.example.DemoGraphQL.model.Author;
import com.example.DemoGraphQL.model.Book;
import com.example.DemoGraphQL.repository.AuthorRepository;
import com.example.DemoGraphQL.repository.BookRepository;

public class AuthorResolver implements GraphQLResolver<Book> {
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public AuthorResolver(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Book> getBooks(Author author) {
        Set<Long> ids = author.getBooks().stream().map(book -> book.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return bookRepository.findAll(ids);
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.DemoGraphQL.model.Author.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I'm able to implement a similar resolver when I'm querying just one object for a given model. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by adding the `fetch=FetchType.Eager` to my many-to-many decorator.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
```

This is obviously not a performant solution at scale.